# GDataXML iOS Escaping & before parse

Tags: objective-c, xml, libxml2, gdata, ampersand

ASIHttpRequest gives me the responsedata of a REST request as an NSData object.

I pass this data object into:

```
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];
```

which produces these errors:

> Entity: line 590: parser error :
>   xmlParseEntityRef: no name
>   Sales &
>   Marketing
>                       ^ Entity: line 602: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef:
>   no name Sales & Marketing

Research has shown me that this has to do with the fact that & needs to be replaced with
"& amp;" before parsing.

But I just cannot find how to do this in a convenient way...

Answer (score 1):

try NSString's `stringByReplacingString:withString:` on the sending side, replacing `@"&"` with `@"&amp;"`.  If you don't have control of the sending side then you may need to do some pre-processing of your returned data or a different way of parsing your XML.